# Sms api working on local server but not working on hosted server

Tags: php, html, curl

In my development environment, i enabled CURL. When i deployed the application via wamp server, everything works fine and i can send SMS when connected to internet. 
Now when i hosted it on my account, it couldn't send SMS rather it displays error showed below

Not Acceptable
An appropriate representation of the requested resource /components/com_spc/smsapi.php could not be found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips DAV/2 mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at www.examplesms.com Port 80

below is the working code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$data = array(
        'username' => $_POST['username'],
        'password' => $_POST['password'],
        'sender'  => $_POST['sender'],
'recipient'  => $_POST['recipient'],
        'message'  => $_POST['message']
);


    // Send the POST request with cURL
    $ch = curl_init('http://www.examplesms.com/components/com_spc/smsapi.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);


 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch); //This is the result from Textlocal


if(curl_exec($ch) === false) {
echo '<font color=red size=4><b>Message sending failed' . '</b></font><br />';
} else {
echo '<font color=orange size=4><b>Message sent successfully' . '</b></font><br />';
echo 'Total number of bytes downloaded: ' . curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD) . '<br />';
echo 'Total size of all headers received: ' . curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE) . '<br />';
}

curl_close($ch);

//var_dump($result);

print($result);
} else {




?>


                <form method="post"  style="margin: 5px; padding: 5px;">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5px" cellpadding="3px">

     <tr>

                                <td><input name="username" type="hidden" id="username" value="" size="50" style="width: 400px;" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                                <td><input name="password" type="hidden" id="password" value="" size="50" style="width: 400px;" /></td>
                        </tr>                   
<tr>

                                <td><input name="sender" type="hidden" id="sender" size="50" style="width: 400px;" value=""/></td>
                        </tr>      
<tr>
                                <td>Reciever</td>
                                <td>

<input name="recipient" type="text" id="recipient" size="50" style="width: 400px;" value=""/>


</td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr>
                                <td>Message</td>
                                <td><textarea name="message" rows="4" cols="90" id="message" style="width: 400px; height: 120px;"></textarea></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                                <td> 

                                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="add_subcat" value="Send Now!" class="btn btn-info btn-small"></input> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset" /></td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
                </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Is that examplesms.com your own server? Or your sms provider's?

Comment: it is my sms provider the actual site is www.nigerianbulksms.com

Answer (score 0):

You are posting the data directly as an array. Which means its using multipart form posting.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

So change it with this one:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

Comment: this is the error: Not Acceptable

An appropriate representation of the requested resource /components/com_spc/smsapi.php could not be found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips DAV/2 mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at www.nigerianbulksms.com Port 80